# Could not produce release apk by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.1.
 I tried producing release apk in two ways, neither works:

1. Using IDE build **menu**--->**generate a signed APK**. For buildType I selected "**release**" .after click Finish, nothing happens. But if I select debug, it will work
2. Try running `./gradlew assembleRelease`, it said task "assembleRelease" not found in project. And I could not found the task in gradle view on the right

So how to produce this task in gradle manually?

Comment: You should post your app build.gradle file

Comment: Can you see any error during build.

Answer (score 0):

add build type in app level gradle  file :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
           }
```

this will work..